# Visual Studio: Naming patterns when adding projects in a solution

Tags: visual-studio

Just out curiosity, I've noticed that many instructors in the `Pluralsight` training videos add projects in a solution following this pattern: **[Solution name].[Project Name]**. For instance:

```
CarDealers.WebUI
CarDealers.Models
CarDealers.Data
```

Why not just call those projects **WebUI**, **Models**, **Data**, etc.. instead of prefixing them? is there any benefit by doing so? Or, it's just a matter of style. Steven Sanderson does not follow that patterns in his books.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The only purpose of nesting in namespaces is to eliminate naming conflicts. For example, if you imported code from a third-party library that also had a `Data` namespace, you'd have a conflict. By nesting your `Data` namespace within a unique `CarDealers` namespace, you avoid this. For trivial examples, like in a book, it is wholly unnecessary. And more than one or two levels of nesting is never necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We typically use [CompanyName].[ProjectName].[SubProject] as the namespace and [ProjectName].[SubProject] for the project name.

For test projects, we append .UnitTest to both the project and namespace name.